# Issue with CSS stylesheets

Tags: css, testing, stylesheet

I have been working on a site for a few days now and uploaded the site to test. In dreamweaver the site looks fine and the CSS styles are being applied. In a browser the CSS does not take. I have checked and re-checked the links and cannot understand where the disconnect is happening. Here is the test site

http://gbetza.mydomain.com/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/index.html

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you show us the code? Especially the stylesheet calls in your header.

Comment: <link href="css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Also, post what the stylesheet is supposed to be styling. Your site.css file looks awfully sparse.

Comment: I've also tried css/site.css

Comment: Did you add the css files to the mentioned directories?

Comment: http://gbetza.mydomain.com/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/site.css

Comment: you're right, the site seems to be linked to an older version of this stylesheet. I've checked the server and the correct one is up there. Not sure what's going on

Comment: I checked your site.css file several minutes ago and when checking it just now it seems to be 10x bigger. So your issue was definitely a case of it not updating. The site looks fine now though, just hit F5 a few times.

Comment: I reuploaded the entire css folder. seems to have fixed most issues. background image is not showing.

Comment: another quick question. This site is responsive, but when I resize the site the slideshow image overlaps the footer. when I refresh, it fixes itself. Is there a way to make that smoother in the CSS?

Thanks again.

Comment: @user3317435 The easiest way to stop the slideshow overlapping the footer would be to give it a min-width for when the site isn't in it's mobile state, as the slideshow doesn't really need to adjust to anything below 625px when in its non-mobile mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time I load the site, your site.css file seems to be getting larger. So I'm pretty sure this is a case of your site.css file not being up-to-date.

If you get this file to the correct version, all of your issues should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cache. Try cachebusting technique. Eg : add css/site.css?v2